# Pass data from controller to view using ajax

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc, razor

Hi i select data from database and i want these data pass from my controller to view via ajax but it is not working.

Please can you help me ?

Here is my controller :

```
[HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Foo(string email_uzivatele)
        {
            var person = AdvertServiceLayer.Instance.SelectByEmail(email_uzivatele);
            return Json(person, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

Here i want display email which i select from database:

```
 <input id="email" name="email_uzivatele" type="text" class="form-control input-md">
```

Here is my ajax function:

```
 $(function () {
            function getPerson(email_uzivatele) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: '@Url.Action("Foo", "Home")',
                    type: 'GET',
                    dataType: 'json',

                    cache: false,
                    data: { email_uzivatele: email_uzivatele },
                    success: function (person) {
                        $('#email').val(person.email_uzivatele);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
```

Here is function which select email from database:

```
        public List<Advert> SelectByEmail(string email_uzivatele)
                {



                    string queryString = "SELECT distinct email_uzivatele from 

    Reklama 
    where email_uzivatele like '%" + @email_uzivatele + "%'";
                    // Create the Command and Parameter objects.
                    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(queryString, Connection);

                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email_uzivatele", "");

                    // Open the connection in a try/catch block. 
                    // Create and execute the DataReader, writing the result
                    // set to the console window.
                    try
                    {

                        SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
                        List<Advert> advert = new List<Advert>();
                        while (reader.Read())
                        {

                            Advert a = new Advert();
                            a.email_uzivatele = reader[0].ToString();



                            Console.WriteLine("email_uzivatele: " + " " + "
 " + a.email_uzivatele);

                            advert.Add(a);
                        }

                        reader.Close();
                        return advert;
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        chyba.zapsat_do_souboru(ex.Message);
                        Console.OpenStandardOutput();
                        Console.WriteLine(ex);
                        //zalogovat chybu
                        return null;
                    }


                }
```

Comment: check if the value is coming properly. Keep a alert alert(person) and alert(person.email_uzivatele) and see if the value is coming properly and just binding is issue

Comment: I added alert a nothing happend. Seriously what am i doing wrong ?

Comment: if your `SelectByEmail` function returns a list.. then your ajax success should use an index to get the value `$('#email').val(person[0].email_uzivatele);`

Comment: Still not working even when i changed in my ajax what you suggested

Comment: you're still not telling us what exactly isn't working.. is the controller action getting hit.. does person has any records before it's returned.. does email_uzivatele contain a value?

Comment: Nothing happens when i open my console in chrome no request from ajax

Answer (score 2):

I think that the problem is coming from the url property. Everything else seems to be correct. The better approach i will recommend you is using Ajax html helper. I show you examples with both - ajax helper and jquery.

Ajax helper approach -> I prefer it because the MVC view stays clean without JS making some requests from different files

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("AddToArticle", "Comments", null, new AjaxOptions
                                                                     {
                                                                         HttpMethod = "POST",
                                                                         InsertionMode = InsertionMode.InsertBefore,
                                                                         UpdateTargetId = "comments-list",
                                                                         OnSuccess = "acceptedComment",
                                                                         OnFailure = "rejectedComment"
                                                                     }))
            {
                @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

                <input type="hidden" value="@Model.Id" name="toId"/>
                <div class="row bottom-margin">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <textarea id="comment-area" class="form-control" placeholder="Коментар" rows="5" name="content"></textarea>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <input type="submit" class="show-more cat-sports" title="Post comment" value="Добави"/>
                </div>
            }
```

Here you can easily put [ValidateAntiForgery] attribute on your action and it will be verified automatically if you have @Html.AntiForgeryToken() in your view. With JS you can validate anti-forgery token too. It prevents you from XSRF attacks and increase your security. Best practices says that it must persist in every POST request.

This is an example with jquery. Your mistake in this case is the url property

You should pass it as url like this:

```
$.ajax({
     url: "/Home/Foo",
```

I hope that this solves your issue. 
Best regards

Comment: PS: You can also use the shorten syntax - 

$.post( "ajax/test.html", function( data ) {
  $( ".result" ).html( data );
});

Comment: I changed my url to url: "/Home/Foo" but it  still is not working and Ajax html helper i don´t know how to use in my case

Answer (score 1):

I've read your question once again and I saw that your concept is wrong. I will explain what I mean in the next couple of rows. So..

There is no such thing as passing a data from controller via ajax. You can pass a data with ajax only from the View to the Controller. It is used in cases of SPA functionality. If you want to load data and display it in the view you should use view model in MVC and load it directly in your view.

I've made you a working example with ajax and I will explain it to you.The first thing is that you haven't called your function.

In this case I've made a simple example to show you what the idea is.

This is the controller

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Foo(string email_uzivatele)
    {
        return Json(email_uzivatele, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

These are the html inputs

```
<input id="email" name="email_uzivatele" type="text" class="form-control input-md">
<input id="submit-btn" type="submit" value="Sumbit" />
```

This is your JS function

```
  $(function () {

    $('#submit-btn').on('click', function () {

        var email_uzivatele = $('#email').val();

        $.ajax({
            url: '/Home/Foo',
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'json',
            cache: false,
            data: { email_uzivatele: email_uzivatele },
            success: function (person) {
                $('#email').val(person.email_uzivatele);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

In this case you pass the value that you are typed in your textbox into the controller via ajax on the submit button click

Comment: Thank you but I was asking this question because i need select data from my database and then i want to display these data in chart using ajax and google charts: https://google-developers.appspot.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/piechart#example. But i have no idea how to do it. Plese any idea how to do it ?